# Metal Core Image kernel workingColorSpace

Tags: ios, metal, core-image, metalkit

I understand that by default, Core image uses extended linear sRGB as default working color space for executing kernels. This means that the color values received (or sampled from sampler) in the Metal Core Image kernel are linear values without gamma correction applied. But if we disable color management by setting

```
let options:[CIContextOption:Any] = [CIContextOption.workingColorSpace:NSNull()];
```

do we receive color values as it exists in the input texture (which may have gamma correction already applied)? In other words, the color values received in the kernel are gamma corrected and we need to manually convert them to linear values in the Metal kernel if required?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should be the case: you receive the color values as they are defined in the input image without any conversion when you disable color management.

Apple seems to have designed this API specifically for working with raw input data that doesn't necessarily encode color values:

> To request that Core Image perform no color management, specify the NSNull object as the value for this key. Use this option for images that don’t contain color data (such as elevation maps, normal vector maps, and sampled function tables).

– [Documenation of `CIContextOption.workingColorSpace`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontextoption/1437728-workingcolorspace#)

Comment: Hmm, so what is the solution if one wants to receive linear values in the kernel?

Comment: Well, the easiest is to let Core Image do the color management for you. Otherwise, you have to implement and apply the EOTF that corresponds to your input yourself.

Comment: Ok, but the problem then is I may receive normalised color values beyond 1.0 and I do not know what is the maximum value I may receive. Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66912225/how-to-correctly-handle-hdr10-in-custom-metal-core-image-kernel) question you answered.

Comment: That's the challenge when filtering EDR content. There is a section in [this WWDC22 video](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc22/10114?time=637) about that. Most notable for you might be the `CIAreaLogarithmicHistogram` filter. You could also try to convert your input to the `linearITUR_2020` color space. I think this will linearize the values and clamp to `[0.0...1.0]`, but I'm not sure if this really works for BT.2100 inputs.

Comment: I have raised a DTS request today, lets hope to hear from them soon.

Comment: Can you please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77773528/scale-and-translate-ciimage-to-center-of-drawable) question?

Comment: @DeepakSharma No need to ping me, I see all new Core Image questions.

Comment: ok will keep that in mind.